# How to hide a table in dataframe while we need it to sort?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 tables combined from 2 dataframes. There are CH1, CH11, and CH12.

I'd like to sort all the tables based on CH1, but I don't want table CH1 appears.

Please help finding the solution.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

csv1=pd.read_csv('auto$0$0.csv')
csv2=pd.read_csv('auto$0$8.csv')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(csv1, columns = ['CH1','CH11','CH12'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(csv2, columns = ['CH1','CH11','CH12'])

dfnew = pd.concat([df1, df2])

dfsort = dfnew.sort_index(by=['CH1'], ascending=True)

print dfsort
```

Comment: Your question makes little sense, can you post representative raw data and the desired output along with a clearer explanation

Comment: Why don't you just delete that column?

Comment: Those are not tables, they are called columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `CH1`. For sorting by column is better use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
import pandas as pd

dict_build = {'CH1': [1,2,3,10,0.1], 'CH11':[1,1,1,1,1], 'CH12': [1,2,3,10,0.1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_build)
print df1
    CH1  CH11  CH12
0   1.0     1   1.0
1   2.0     1   2.0
2   3.0     1   3.0
3  10.0     1  10.0
4   0.1     1   0.1

dict_build = {'CH1': [10,2,3,7,9], 'CH11':[1,1,1,1,1], 'CH12': [1,2,3,10,0.1]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_build)
print df2
   CH1  CH11  CH12
0   10     1   1.0
1    2     1   2.0
2    3     1   3.0
3    7     1  10.0
4    9     1   0.1

dfnew = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print dfnew
    CH1  CH11  CH12
0   1.0     1   1.0
1   2.0     1   2.0
2   3.0     1   3.0
3  10.0     1  10.0
4   0.1     1   0.1
0  10.0     1   1.0
1   2.0     1   2.0
2   3.0     1   3.0
3   7.0     1  10.0
4   9.0     1   0.1
```

```
dfsort = dfnew.sort_values(by=['CH1'], ascending=True)
print dfsort
    CH1  CH11  CH12
4   0.1     1   0.1
0   1.0     1   1.0
1   2.0     1   2.0
1   2.0     1   2.0
2   3.0     1   3.0
2   3.0     1   3.0
3   7.0     1  10.0
4   9.0     1   0.1
3  10.0     1  10.0
0  10.0     1   1.0

print dfsort.drop('CH1', axis=1)
   CH11  CH12
4     1   0.1
0     1   1.0
1     1   2.0
1     1   2.0
2     1   3.0
2     1   3.0
3     1  10.0
4     1   0.1
3     1  10.0
0     1   1.0
```

Comment: whoa that was quick. thanks for the reply!! it works.

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!